# How can I format a number as currency in Perl?

Tags: perl, format

How I can format this for example:

100000 as 1000.00

and

90 as 0.90

using Perl?

I found and try with some modules like `Locale::Currency::Format` and `Number::Format`, but nothing work :/

With `Locale::Currency::Format` I try:

```
use Locale::Currency::Format;
my $total = 19750;
my $convert = currency_format('USD',$total,'FMT_COMMON');
print $convert;
```

I've expect 197.50 but the print are "19,750.00 USD".

Comment: [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) You might need to divide by 100 first, if 19750 is cents, rather than dollars.

Comment: Note: if you set `$total = 19750`, that's what will come out. You may have wanted `$total = 197.50` instead, or divide your value by 100? But you'll need consistency in the way you use your numbers, because your 2 examples aren't consistent between themselves.

Comment: @AntonH Sorry, I forgot to mention in post, the value are receveid from an API like this:

      {"result":{"appid":730,"contextid":2,"items":{name)":19800}}}

19800

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert cents into dollars, divide by 100!

```
sprintf("%.2f", $total/100)                        # 197.50
```

or

```
currency_format('USD', $total/100, 'FMT_COMMON')   # 197.50 USD
```

Comment: Sorry, it's really unclear, I forgot to mention in post, the value is received from an API like : 

    {"result":{"appid":730,"contextid":2,"items":{name)":19800}}‌​} 

    198.00

    {"result":{"appid":730,"contextid":2,"items":{name)":90}}‌​}

     0.90 

the value depends of the item in API

Answer (score 6):

```
my $formatted = sprintf '%.2f', $number/100.0;
```

In US currency we count dollars, not cents. If you want to use integers representing pennies to avoid rounding errors, that's great; good practice. But it's up to you to divide by 100 to get human-legible output in the standard format.

The [`sprintf`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) function (**s**tring **print** **f**ormatted, originally from the C standard library and now found in many programming languages) will format numbers in a variety of ways. In this case, the format string `%.2f` requests output of a **f**loating-point (i.e. decimal, fractional, real, non-integer) number with 2 digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

**Update for late 2022**:

Using this method:

```
use Locale::Currency::Format;
...
$dollars = currency_format('USD',1,624.98,FMT_SYMBOL);
```

Outputs this:

```
$1.00
```

I have just run into this issue and had to insert this before the format:

```
use Locale::Currency::Format;
...
$dollars =~ s/\,//g;  #<----------
$dollars = currency_format('USD',$dollars,FMT_SYMBOL);
```